# RadTreeView just suddenly changed to hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radtreeview

In development environment (VS 2010) the RadTreeView works perfectly well, but when I deploy my solution on Windows Server 2003 the RadTreeView changes to hyperlinks and I can't expand them anymore.

Comment: Make sure **EnableEmbeddedSkin** is not set to **false** *(By default it is true)*, and **Skin** has valid **name**. Otherwise, we need more information -  ASP.Net or MVC, Version of Telerik control.

Comment: @win thank you for your reply, but it didnt work on the server it just shows hyperlinks without even the expansion signs, mean while on my local system it works fine even when i change the skins. i am using Asp.net with telerik version 2011.3.1317.40. please Note it was working fine until i replaced the build, and ever since then its been like this (i.e links)

Answer (score 2):

My **telerik 2013.2.717.40** doesn't render Skin in VS 2013, although it works fine in VS 2012.

However, **telerik 2014.1.403.40** fixes VS 2013 issue.

The answer is your **telerik 2011.3.1317.40** is quite old, so you need to update those dlls in order to support new browsers such as IE11.

Even if you create a support ticket with Telerik, they'll ask you the same thing.

***FYI:*** 2014.2 618 release last week, but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Well, you need to [login](http://www.telerik.com/account/) with your Telerik account and download it from there.

Comment: but @win why does it work on my local system both when using Visual Studio and when i deploy on my local machine. and my system is really more updated than my server in all aspects.

Comment: probably having a more updated dev env than the deployment env breaks stuff. See the end of my answer for a common IE10+.net4 problem

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the CDNs:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/stylesheetmanager-cdn-support.html
and
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager-cdn-support.html

Also, if the problem is in IE - probably your old version does not support the new IE.On localhost your IE was, most likely, in compatibility mode (i.e., something like IE7) and things worked fine.

Now, when deployed, your IE is in edge mode and breaks stuff. 2011.3 would not support IE10, IE11 or the new Chrome and Firefox browsers (they've had like 20 versions since).

There are even more problems that can arise from deploying and accessing with IE - .NET4 will not recognize IE10 and IE11, see how to fix it here: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-12-19/how-to-get-your-asp.net-application-working-in-ie11.